# ¿Cómo eliminar archivo “AUTORUN.INF” de una USB?

Tags: archivo, windows, consola, proceso

**Equipo**

- Estoy utilizando Windows 7 Professional.
- Tengo el rol de Administrador.
- El dispositivo USB tiene sistema de archivos FAT32.

**Situación**:
En la carpeta raíz de una USB aparece un archivo llamado “AUTORUN.INF”, el cual quiero eliminar, al intentar hacerlo por el explorador de Windows, me aparece el mensaje: “Se requieren permisos de administrador del equipo para hacer cambios en este archivo”. He intentado las siguientes alternativas sin éxito.

**Alternativas probadas:**

1. Quitar todos los atributos del archivo (Archivo de solo lectura, archivo de almacenamiento, archivo del sistema, archivo oculto) por medio de la consola de mando de Windows.

```
Attrib –r –a –s –h I:/AUTORUN.INF
```

Obteniendo el siguiente resultado negativo:

```
Acceso denegado: I:/AUTORUN.INF
```

2. Consultar que proceso está utilizando el archivo con el programa Process Explorer para luego matar el proceso con el programa "Handle V4.0" como lo sugiere esta [solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-specific-file-is-open-in-windows)

Atajo Ctrl + F, para acceder a la funcionalidad “Handle or DLL substring”, luego buscar por “`I:/AUTORUN.INF`”, me da como respuesta “0 marching items”

3. Probar el programa [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/).

Hice caso omiso a la advertancia “sitio sospechoso de servir software no deseado”, lo descargue e instalé, al darle clic derecho sobre el archivo y luego elegir Unlocker me muestra que el archivo no está bloqueado por ningún proceso, pero no permite eliminarlo, solicita hacerlo después del siguiente reinicio, pero al final tampoco lo elimina.

**Alternativas no probadas**

1. Utilizar un mini Linux, mini Windows o BootCD

Alternativa demorada, no tengo esas herramientas.

2. Formatear la USB.

Implica movimiento de datos bastente demorado.

3. Eliminarlo utilizando modo seguro de windows.

¿Existe una solución que no implique reiniciar el equipo?

Comment: Formatear el USB es una opción?

Comment: @JoelIbaceta es una opción que quiero evitar, tranferir toda la información a otro dispositivo para luego formaterla y volver a agregar la info a la USB, toma tiempo.

Comment: Según la descripción del sitio: __Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software__ Yo me pregunto, en este contexto ¿Qué tiene que ver un dispositivo USB con programación?

Comment: Programación incluye manipulación y administración de archivos, no importa si estos están en un Disco Duro, Memoria RAM, Dispositivo USB, MicroSD, granos de arroz, etc. ** Stack Overflow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software**, hablando en este contexto, en múltiples ocasiones el software está ligado con el hardware @Hector

Comment: @Goerman si necesitas, por ejemplo, modificar un archivo desde tu software (PROGRAMACIÓN), entonces si sería valido. Según lo que tú dices alguien podría preguntar _¿cómo puedo borrar los archivos de una carpeta?_ y eso no tiene nada que ver com programación tampoco, a menos que quieras eliminar esos archivos mediante el software que estás programando.

Comment: Me está diciendo que la comunidad Stack Overflow no es una comunidad para entusiastas en el uso de software? aún no entiendo tu punto @Hector, por favor explicame.

Comment: Bueno, creo que ya he expuesto mis argumentos, sólo decir que personalmente considero esta no es una pregunta relacionada al uso de un software ni relacionada con programación. saludos

Comment: @Hector "Preguntas y respuestas para programadores y profesionales de la informática" esta pregunta si que tiene cabida ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTA:** He colocado esta respuesta por parte de la otra , ya que claramente aborda el problema en  una manera muy diferente y es para cubrir un caso muy específico.

### Opción 4 : [Panda USB Vaccine](http://www.pandasecurity.com/spain/enterprise/downloads/usbvaccine/)

Resulta que **Panda USB Vaccine** hace uso de los atributos del archivo, PERO de los atributos no documentados, estableciendo en 1 un valor que de acuerdo a la documentación de Microsoft que siempre debe estar en 0.

En el formato de archivo el último byte después del nombre representa los permisos de esta forma

```
XYADVSHR

X, Y: reservados por Windows (Y en 1 indica que el archivo apunta a un dispositivo , por ejemplo los archivos reservados CON, LPT etc)
R: ATTR_READ_ONLY   0x01
H: ATTR_HIDDEN      0x02
S: ATTR_SYSTEM      0x04
V: ATTR_VOLUME_ID   0x08
D: ATTR_DIRECTORY   0x10
A: ATTR_ARCHIVE     0x20
```

Si uno revisa la configuración de ese BYTE para **AUTORUN.INF** en un editor RAW de disco encuentra el valor `42` hexadecimal que equivale a estos bytes

```
01000010
XYADVSHR
```

Si te fijas, establece `Y` en `1`, ese atributo es reservado y lo que hace es **decirle a Windows que ese archivo es realmente un dispositivo**, de tal forma que para Windows este archivo no se debe borrar.

Así que hay que reescribir los atributos del archivo a nivel del sistema de archivos, para hacerlo sigue estos pasos:

1. consigue un editor binario de discos, hay varios pero te recomiendo [**iBored**](http://apps.tempel.org/iBored/)
2. una vez instalado, ejecútalo como administrador y abre la unidad usb desde el tool
   [image: iBored open disk]
3. una vez 'abierta' presiona `CTRL + F` para buscar `AUTORUN INF` **<<--- OJO SIN EL PUNTO, CON ESPACIO**. Presta atención a los detalles, como por ejemplo usar case sensitive para que la búsqueda sea más rápida , ya que podría tomar mucho tiempo.

   [image: View Raw contents]
4. Una vez encontrado selecciona el nombre del archivo en el Editor de texto, fíjate en el caracter hexa que le sigue que equivalen a los atributos del archivo (en este caso 0x42).
   [image: buscar bytes de permisos]
   1.Presiona `Ctrl + Shift + M` para hacer el disco escribible, te pueden salir errores, sobre todo en Windows 10. Ignora los errores dando click en Cancelar.

   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
5. Ahora selecciona el `42` y reemplazalo por `20` lo que en esencia es marcar el archivo como listo para archivar y dejar los demás atributos en 0, presiona `Save`
6. Cierra **iBored**  y listo, ya puedes borrar el archivo.

Comment: Archivo eliminado con exito utlizando la herramienta iBored! Solamente modifique el 42 por 20, los otros atributos los deje tal cual como estaban.

Comment: Cuando cambias 42 por 20 has cambiado **todos** los atributos a 0 con excepción del atributo A.

Comment: Gracias!, se solucionó con iBored, excelente explicación.

Answer (score 8):

**Unlocker** es confiable, pero te enseñaré a hacerlo con Windows.

Para todas las opciones que te muestro abre la consola en modo administrador , click derecho sobre el icono y seleccionas la "Run as administrator"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y antes de cualquier cosa verifica la integridad del sistema de archivos

```
sfc /SCANFILE=I:\autorun.inf
```

Sino te funciona, has chequeo completo del sistema

```
sfc /SCANNOW
```

### Opcíón 1

Ejecuta estos comandos, puede ser necesario "matar" `explorer.exe` para poder borrar el archivo (explorer lo puede haber bloqueado), y se usa `/F` para poderlo borrar aunque esté en solo lectura.

```
TASKKILL /F /IM explorer.exe
del "I:\AUTORUN.INF" /F /Q /A
explorer
```

---

### Opción 2

El escenario puede ser más adverso si un ejecutable ha bloqueado el archivo, en ese caso descarga esta herramienta de Microsoft y ejecuta lo siguiente también como administrador.

#### [Handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
handle "I:\AUTORUN.INF"
Algo.exe             pid: 4      type: File          3BE8: I:\AUTORUN.INF
Otro.exe             pid: 5      type: File          40C0: I:\AUTORUN.INF
```

Ahora si entonces matas los procesos usando el pid y `taskkill`

```
TASKKILL /PID 4 /PID 5 /T
del "I:\AUTORUN.INF" /F /Q /A
```

---

### Opción 3

Puede que de plano no tengas permiso, parece tu caso, entonces toma posesión del archivo:

```
takeown /F "I:\AUTORUN.INF"
```

Y luego asigna el permiso de borrar.

```
icacls "I:\AUTORUN.INF" /grant MyUser:(D,W)
```

Para ahora si borrar

```
del "I:\AUTORUN.INF" /F /Q
```

Comment: Primera opción, fallo ver imágen (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7vg4TlCNOkZYWpKN1NDUjJEZU0/view). Probando segunda opción, descargue el handle, lo ejecute cómo administrador, con este resultado: ""handle" no ser reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable" Investigando ...

Comment: He adicionado /A a los delete.  1 . No ejecutes los comandos desde I:\ 2. Handle debes descargarlo 3. Sino has matado explorer en el paso 1. Lo demás de ese paso no servirá

Comment: Las opciones no sirvieron. tanto con el explorer activo o no activo. ver imágen (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7vg4TlCNOkZXy1vVlFMMEJuUDA/view?)

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta con otra solución posible

Comment: Al ejecutar takeown /F "I:\AUTORUN.INF": Error: no se puede establecer la propiedad de archivos en sistemas de archivos no seguros; no hay compatibilidad con ACLs

Comment: es una USB formateada en FAT32? en ese caso no puedes tomar ownership ni settear algunos permisos. Incluye ese detalle en la definición de la pregunta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33288/discussion-between-juank-and-goerman).

Comment: He adicionado soporte para remover la protección de **Panda USB Vaccine**, ya que es muy probable que ese sea tu caso.

Answer (score 3):

Parece que se haya aplicado el [Panda USB Vaccine](http://www.pandasecurity.com/spain/enterprise/downloads/usbvaccine/) a la unidad.

Esta herramienta, para evitar que los virus puedan usar un `autorun.inf` para ejecutarse desde el disquete o usb, permite crear (o crea automáticamente para todas las unidades que se inserten) un autorun.inf `erróneo` (si no recuerdo mal incluía los atributos de sistema, oculto, volumen…), de tal manera que aunque se muestra que el fichero existe, no es posible leer, borrar ni modificar el fichero.

Si no puedes acceder al fichero ni siquiera nada más reiniciar, me inclino porque se trate de esta opción. También puedes mirar si `attrib autorun.inf` da alguna pista al respecto.

La propia herramienta (es un programa gratuito) permite *desvacunar* una unidad.

Comment: muy interesante trabajaré sobre ello para complementar mi respuesta

Comment: La herramienta de panda no deja desvacunar

Comment: @JuanK la herramienta sí lo permite, se ve incluso en la [captura de pantalla](http://www.pandasecurity.com/spain/enterprise/downloads/usbvaccine/]): “Remove vaccine”.

Comment: Será en al versión paga? la he bajado para replicar el caso y en Windows 10 no me sale :S

Comment: @JuanK Que yo sepa no hay versión de pago. Lo único que se me ocurre es que dependiera de poder abrir discos duros directamente y por eso no funcione en una versión moderna como Windows 10. Pero en tal caso, tampoco podría vacunar…

Comment: El screenshot muestra que la vacuna se puede remover del PC no de la usb.

Comment: El screenshot muestra que la vacuna se puede remover del PC no de la usb. @Ángel

Comment: @JuanK eso explica la captura de pantalla. Sin embargo, me parece recordar que se podía hacer. Quizá por ser otra versión de Windows.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso funciono **iBored**, una vez desbloqueado el archivo lo abri y solo tenia dentro unas cuantas letras, nada de codigo malicioso. Creo que lo que hace este archivo, colocado por un virus previmente removido, es que bloquea el autorun del USB para evitar que se ejecute cualquier otra cosa y poder tomar control del USB.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado [PsExec](https://download.sysinternals.com/files/PSTools.zip)?

Si el problema es de permisos, quizá el archivo lo pueda manipular solo la cuenta de SYSTEM, y aquí es donde entra PsExec.

Copia el ejecutable en System32 por ejemplo, y luego desde el símbolo del sistema lanza:

> **PsExec -SID cmd.exe**

Esto abrirá otro CMD con privilegios de SYSTEM; lo que sigue es que navegues hasta el archivo y utilices ya algún comando conocido como:

```
DEL autorun.inf
```

Comment: pintaba super bien, pero acabo de probarlo y no :(  En la consola cargada como sys me dice `Could Not Find I:\autorun.inf`

Comment: Incluso ejecutando del "I:\AUTORUN.INF" /F /Q /A desde la nueva consola con privilegios de System32 me aparece: I:\AUTORUN.INF Acceso denegado.

Comment: Empiezo a creer que quizá se debe al dispositivo. 

Descarga Accesschk desde live.sysinternals.com, copia el ejecutable en System32 y desde un símbolo del sistema con privilegios elevados, lanza, por ejemplo:

`accesschk  F:\autorun.inf`

Donde F:\ naturalmente es tu unidad. Eso debe darte los permisos completos que hay sobre el archivo. Muéstranos.

Comment: @Checho Revisa mi otra respuesta más arriba : http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/1501/398 , no es por tema de permisos porque FAT32 no los soporta, es problema atributos pero los atributos reservados del sistema, por lo que no hay forma 'limpia' de cambiarlos. de todas manera para documentarnos corrí el comando y: ` Error getting security:
  Access is denied.`

Answer (score 0):

Yo tenía el mismo problema, no era un virus, simplemente no podía borrar el autorun.inf de la raiz de las USB.

Mi solución fue desactivar la Vacuna USB de Panda Antivirus, sin embargo, esto no elimina el autorun.inf, sino que no lo vuelve a crear con las nuevas memorias. A las que ya lo tienen hay que formatearla. Parece que el autorun.inf esta dañado (aproposito por Panda) y no se puede tocar.

[image: Panda USB Vaccine]